# undefined reference to...collect2:error:ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++, linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am writing a simple program to compile from the command prompt. There is an `app1` program that uses a class located in a separate file. The class `sample1` has a header file `sample1.h` where all the function declarations exist. The `sample1.cpp` file contains the function definitions.

`app1.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "sample1.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    sample1 t;
    cout<<"The program is ending"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

`sample1.h`:

```
#ifndef SAMPLE1_H
#define SAMPLE1_H

class sample1
{       
    public:
    sample1();
};

#endif
```

`sample1.cpp`:

```
#include<sample1.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

sample1::sample1()
{
    cout<<"This error sucks"<<endl;
}
```

I am compiling this program using Windows Subsystem for Linux. However, when I try to compile with `g++ 'app1.cpp' -o app1`, I get this error:
[image]

I get that the error is telling me that the program cannot find the constructor `sample::sample()` but why is that? I included the header file in the program. These 3 files all exist in the same folder.

Comment: Can you point out exactly at which step you are compiling and linking with your second `.cpp` file?

Comment: This was my mistake. I was not compiling and linking `app1.cpp` and `sample1.cpp`. I changed the command to `g++ app1.cpp sample1.cpp -o app1` and changed `#include <sample1.h>` in `sample1.cpp` to `#include "sample1.h"`. The program works fine now!

Comment: The compiler is not going to look at `sample1.cpp` just because its name happens to be similar to something that exists in the text of `app1.cpp`. You need to tell the compiler to look at it.

Comment: "changed `#include <sample1.h>` You traded a mistake for a worse mistake. Don't do that.

Answer (score 3):

You have to compile all your `.cpp` files (`sample1.h` is included by preprocessor from information in `app1.cpp` only):

```sh
g++ app1.cpp sample1.cpp -o app1
```

Comment: should remove the extra 'g++' :)